# CMake generates project for VS2022 but it breaks if I generate for MinGW makefiles or Ninja

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, ninja

I have a project where there a couple of dynamic libraries and static one which is completely made in VS 2022, Now I have to port that, for other computer where I can't install VS 2022 or other versions (frankly I don't have admin privileges'). I have tried meson but it does not suffice, now I revisited CMake and successful in building the whole project with cl compiler, but when I generate the project for ninja or MinGW g++, it fails at compiler checking stage, and If I set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS flag TRUE, CMake generates files but it fails at linking stage

this is my CMakeLists.txt

```bash
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
project(myproject CXX)

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Define library sources
set(LIB_SOURCES
    lib.cpp
    lib.h
)

# Build dynamic library
add_library(mylibrary SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(mylibrary PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME mylibrary
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin
  WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE
  DEFINE_SYMBOL MYDLL_EXPORTS
)

install(TARGETS mylibrary
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION bin
)

# Define executable sources
set(EXE_SOURCES
    main.cpp
)

# Build executable and link with library
add_executable(myexecutable ${EXE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myexecutable mylibrary)

# Specify installation targets
install(TARGETS mylibrary DESTINATION lib)
install(TARGETS myexecutable DESTINATION bin)
```

I tried with meson with no DLL only static linking, the sample project works but If I want to dynamically link using ninja it errors out with the log file as

```yaml
---
events:
  -
    kind: "message-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:204 (message)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)"
    message: |
      The system is: Windows - 10.0.19044 - AMD64
  -
    kind: "message-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:17 (message)"
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:64 (__determine_compiler_id_test)"
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:126 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)"
    message: |
      Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
      Compiler: C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/c++.exe 
      Build flags: 
      Id flags:  
      
      The output was:
      0
      
      
      Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"
      
      The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in:
        C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/3.26.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe
      
  -
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:57 (try_compile)"
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:26 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ABI)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)"
    checks:
      - "Detecting CXX compiler ABI info"
    directories:
      source: "C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-b59oa6"
      binary: "C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-b59oa6"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ""
    buildResult:
      variable: "CMAKE_CXX_ABI_COMPILED"
      cached: true
      stdout: |
        Change Dir: C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-b59oa6
        
        Run Build Command(s):C:/m/ninja/ninja.exe -v cmTC_ba170 && [1/2] C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe   -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj -c C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
        Using built-in specs.
        COLLECT_GCC=C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe
        Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
        Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-12.2.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64 --enable-host-shared --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib ' LD_FOR_TARGET=/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/bin/ld.exe --with-boot-ldflags=' -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
        Thread model: posix
        Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
        gcc version 12.2.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/'
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/ -D_REENTRANT C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -quiet -dumpdir CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/ -dumpbase CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=core2 -march=nocona -version -o C:\\Users\\RAGS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccp9IE9Q.s
        GNU C++17 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
            compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP
        
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++"
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++/backward"
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include"
        ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64D:/a/_temp/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../include"
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed"
        ignoring duplicate directory "C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
        ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/mingw/include"
        #include "..." search starts here:
        #include <...> search starts here:
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include/c++/backward
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/include-fixed
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
        End of search list.
        GNU C++17 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) version 12.2.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
            compiled by GNU C version 12.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.25-GMP
        
        GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
        Compiler executable checksum: 1f9e7e6d1fd0042d99a7c746ef8512d8
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/'
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj C:\\Users\\RAGS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccp9IE9Q.s
        GNU assembler version 2.38 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.38
        COMPILER_PATH=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
        LIBRARY_PATH=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../\x0d
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.'\x0d
        [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj -o cmTC_ba170.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_ba170.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0   && cd ."
        FAILED: cmTC_ba170.exe 
        cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj -o cmTC_ba170.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_ba170.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0   && cd ."
        Using built-in specs.
        COLLECT_GCC=C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe
        COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
        Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
        Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-12.2.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64 --enable-host-shared --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/buildroot/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib ' LD_FOR_TARGET=/c/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64/bin/ld.exe --with-boot-ldflags=' -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc'
        Thread model: posix
        Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
        gcc version 12.2.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 
        COMPILER_PATH=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
        LIBRARY_PATH=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../
        COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_ba170.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2' '-march=nocona' '-dumpdir' 'cmTC_ba170.'
         C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\\Users\\RAGS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cc7xQvPe.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-liconv -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 --sysroot=C:/buildroot/x86_64-1220-posix-seh-rt_v10-rev0/mingw64 -m i386pep -Bdynamic -o cmTC_ba170.exe C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0 -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj --out-implib libcmTC_ba170.dll.a --major-image-version 0 --minor-image-version 0 -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -liconv -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/crtend.o
        C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba170.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj: No such file or directory
        collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
        
      exitCode: 1
  -
    kind: "try_compile-v1"
    backtrace:
      - "C:/m/cmake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:49 (try_compile)"
      - "CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)"
    checks:
      - "Check for working CXX compiler: C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/c++.exe"
    directories:
      source: "C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nt8khh"
      binary: "C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nt8khh"
    cmakeVariables:
      CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ""
    buildResult:
      variable: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS"
      cached: true
      stdout: |
        Change Dir: C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nt8khh
        
        Run Build Command(s):C:/m/ninja/ninja.exe -v cmTC_50d8e && [1/2] C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_50d8e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c C:/Users/RAGS/Desktop/Dev_Env/no_version_control/tc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-nt8khh/testCXXCompiler.cxx
        [2/2] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_50d8e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_50d8e.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_50d8e.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
        FAILED: cmTC_50d8e.exe 
        cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\\m\\gcc-compiler\\mingw64\\bin\\c++.exe   CMakeFiles/cmTC_50d8e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -o cmTC_50d8e.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_50d8e.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
        C:/m/gcc-compiler/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find CMakeFiles/cmTC_50d8e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj: No such file or directory\x0d
        collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
        
      exitCode: 1
...
```

PS I'm not a computer major, just a enthusiast, forgive me if the question is simple, Thanks in advance

this is my sample project

```cpp
file lib.cpp
#include"lib.h"
int foo::add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

file lib.h
namespace foo
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}

file main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "lib.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"main is working \n";
    std::cout<<" 5 + 5 = "<<foo::add(5,5);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to link lib dynamically

Comment: If CMake fails at the compiler checking stage it should have produced a debug log file. Please edit your question with the contents of that log file

Comment: "when I generate the project for ninja or MinGW g++, it fails at compiler checking stage, and If I set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS flag TRUE, CMake generates files but it fails at linking stage" - Eh? 1. CMake tells  you that you have a problem with compilers. 2. You tell CMake that there is no problems by setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS` variable. 3. When building the project you got the error. Exactly as CMake told you...

Comment: @Botje I have updated the question with the log file, and set the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS flag false. I have tried on my other system with no VS compiler only with MinGW compiler, but with same error, Thanks in advance

Comment: Failure to produce a .obj file tends to be caused by overzealous virus scanners. Try adding an exclusion for your source directory.

Comment: @Botje I tried once again in my PC yet I see similar error, it fails at libcmTC.dll.a creation step, I have compared the log files side by side and couldn't figure out why it does that. again thanks for showing where it might go wrong ...

Comment: I have found the issue opened in github [link](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/2257)